# How to disable Input hide on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've setup a form with bootstrap columns, collapse and fields, everything is working correctly but the input field. I want to be able to hide all non-selected input fields on click.

Is there a way to do this?

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Zenko/m31ucxvj/2/)

Also, I've tried using `$('.collapse').collapse("hide");` which does hide all the other non-selected fields but when trying to enter text the field hides.

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Zenko/okkqw2we/3/)

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-4 pricing-wrap">
      <label class="pricing text-center" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#con-amount-wrap" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="con-amount-wrap">
        <div class="panel panel-default panel-pricing text-center">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <span class="min-ammount small">Minimum Deposit</span>
            <h3 class="panel-amount">$2,500</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </label>
      <!-- Deposit Amount -->
      <div class="collapse" id="con-amount-wrap">
        <div class="top-buffer-sm">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="con_amount" id="con_amount" placeholder="Deposit Amount" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 pricing-wrap">
      <label class="pricing text-center" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mod-amount-wrap" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="mod-amount-wrap">
        <div class="panel panel-default panel-pricing text-center">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <span class="min-ammount small">Minimum Deposit</span>
            <h3 class="panel-amount">$10,000</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </label>
      <!-- Deposit Amount -->
      <div class="collapse" id="mod-amount-wrap">
        <div class="top-buffer-sm">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mod_amount" id="mod_amount" placeholder="Deposit Amount" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 pricing-wrap">
      <label class="pricing text-center" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#adv-amount-wrap" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="adv-amount-wrap">

        <div class="panel panel-default panel-pricing text-center">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <span class="min-ammount small">Minimum Deposit</span>
            <h3 class="panel-amount">$25,000</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </label>
      <!-- Deposit Amount -->
      <div class="collapse" id="adv-amount-wrap">
        <div class="top-buffer-sm">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="adv_amount" id="adv_amount" placeholder="Deposit Amount" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(".pricing-wrap").click(function (e) {
  $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
  $('.collapse').collapse("hide");
});
```

Comment: So you want keep opened only those boxes that have the input field filled with some value. Otherwise close them when you click on another box?

Comment: try event on click even on labels only  $(".pricing").click(function (e) {
  $(this).parent().addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
  $('.collapse').collapse("hide");
}); working copy https://jsfiddle.net/farazadeo/okkqw2we/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While both label and input fields are within same container so when you click on input box it trigger a click on wrapper. so you need to add event on label and find its wrapper using `parent()` and work on it

`$(".pricing").click(function (e) {
  $(this).parent().addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
  $('.collapse').collapse("hide");
});`

https://jsfiddle.net/farazadeo/okkqw2we/5/

Comment: I'm marking this the answer as it's more cleaner and simpler. Thank you very much! 

Side note, I was trying to get parent() to work earlier but with no results. Looking at your code, it looks like I had parent() in the wrong spot haha but This helps, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your approach of using `$('.collapse').collapse("hide");` is correct, the problem is that when you click the input to focus it, the events propagates and triggers your click event listener on `".pricing-wrap"`. Solution is to bind the click event on the input and stop the event propagation.

See fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/m31ucxvj/3/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this does help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter out the currently selected `.pricing-wrap`

```
$(".pricing-wrap").click(function (e) {
  $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
  $('.collapse').filter(function(){
     return !$(this).closest('.pricing-wrap').hasClass("selected");
  }).collapse("hide");
});
```

Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/okkqw2we/4/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think @Faraz comment is even more cleaner as the code only adds parent() and changing the selector to the <label> instead of .pricing-wrap.

Comment: @Zenko Sure np.. But I think you had marked it accepted and removed it later, it's not accepted as of now :)

Comment: Right, this was before @Faraz posted his answer or more like moved his comment to an answer. I appreciate the help though!

Answer (score 1):

Simple way

```
$(".pricing-wrap").click(function (e) {
    var $s = $(this).addClass("selected");
    $s.siblings()
    .removeClass("selected")
    .find('.collapse.in').removeClass('in');
});
```